# Format integer in Lua

Tags: lua, formatting, integer

I'd like to format a number to look like `1,234` or `1,234,432` or `123,456,789`, you get the idea. I tried doing this as follows:

```
function reformatint(i)
    local length = string.len(i)
    for v = 1, math.floor(length/3) do
        for k = 1, 3 do
            newint = string.sub(mystring, -k*v)
        end
        newint = ','..newint
    end
    return newint
end
```

As you can see, a failed attempt, my problem is that I can't figure out what the error is because the program I am running this in refuses to report an error back to me.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a function that takes negative numbers, and fractional parts into account:

```
function format_int(number)

  local i, j, minus, int, fraction = tostring(number):find('([-]?)(%d+)([.]?%d*)')

  -- reverse the int-string and append a comma to all blocks of 3 digits
  int = int:reverse():gsub("(%d%d%d)", "%1,")

  -- reverse the int-string back remove an optional comma and put the 
  -- optional minus and fractional part back
  return minus .. int:reverse():gsub("^,", "") .. fraction
end

assert(format_int(1234)              == '1,234')
assert(format_int(1234567)           == '1,234,567')
assert(format_int(123456789)         == '123,456,789')
assert(format_int(123456789.1234)    == '123,456,789.1234')
assert(format_int(-123456789.)       == '-123,456,789')
assert(format_int(-123456789.1234)   == '-123,456,789.1234')
assert(format_int('-123456789.1234') == '-123,456,789.1234')

print('All tests passed!')
```

Comment: If you include decimals (not asked for), why didn't you include comma-separation for them?

Comment: I found this when looking for fix for `string.format("%.1f", mynumber)` rounding numbers - I've resolved it by string match - `tostring(mynumber):match("^%d+%.%d")` (not rounding was more preferred in my case)

Answer (score 7):

Well, let's take this from the top down. First of all, it's failing because you've got a reference error:

```
    ...
        for k = 1, 3 do
            newint = string.sub(mystring, -k*v) -- What is 'mystring'?
        end
    ...
```

Most likely you want `i` to be there, not `mystring`.

Second, while replacing `mystring` with `i` will fix the errors, it still won't work correctly.

```
> =reformatint(100)
,100
> =reformatint(1)
,000
```

That's obviously not right. It seems like what you're trying to do is go through the string, and build up the new string with the commas added. But there are a couple of problems...

```
function reformatint(i)
    local length = string.len(i)
    for v = 1, math.floor(length/3) do
        for k = 1, 3 do -- What is this inner loop for?
            newint = string.sub(mystring, -k*v) -- This chops off the end of
                                                -- your string only
        end
        newint = ','..newint -- This will make your result have a ',' at
                             -- the beginning, no matter what
    end
    return newint
end
```

With some rework, you can get a function that work.

```
function reformatint(integer)
    for i = 1, math.floor((string.len(integer)-1) / 3) do
        integer = string.sub(integer, 1, -3*i-i) ..
                  ',' ..
                  string.sub(integer, -3*i-i+1)
    end
    return integer
end
```

The function above seems to work correctly. However, it's fairly convoluted... Might want to make it more readable.

As a side note, a [quick google search](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FormattingNumbers) finds a function that has already been made for this:

```
function comma_value(amount)
  local formatted = amount
  while true do  
    formatted, k = string.gsub(formatted, "^(-?%d+)(%d%d%d)", '%1,%2')
    if (k==0) then
      break
    end
  end
  return formatted
end
```

Comment: uff, I ripped the bit containing mystring from a webpage, obviously I was silly enough to forget to swap that out.

as it turns out, my google searches was terribly incorrect.

I would like to thank you, and I will look into much deeper how string.sub() operates. I hope that my stupidity thus far will atleast let me learn something.

Comment: @Hultin: No need to look down on yourself - we all make mistakes, and they are sometimes silly ones. That is how we learn. And yes, understanding `string.sub()` is a worthwhile endeavor - it is actually slightly different than substring functions in other languages. Also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 3):

You can do without loops:

```
function numWithCommas(n)
  return tostring(math.floor(n)):reverse():gsub("(%d%d%d)","%1,")
                                :gsub(",(%-?)$","%1"):reverse()
end

assert(numWithCommas(100000) == "100,000")
assert(numWithCommas(100) == "100")
assert(numWithCommas(-100000) == "-100,000")
assert(numWithCommas(10000000) == "10,000,000")
assert(numWithCommas(10000000.00) == "10,000,000")
```

The second gsub is needed to avoid -,100 being generated.

Answer (score 1):

I remember discussing about this in the [LÖVE forums](https://love2d.org/forums) ... let me look for it...

[Found it](https://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1802)!

This will work with positive integers:

```
function reformatInt(i)
  return tostring(i):reverse():gsub("%d%d%d", "%1,"):reverse():gsub("^,", "")
end
```

On the link above you may read details about implementation.