# printf formatting in lua

Tags: c, lua, printf, coronasdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lua - Format integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989788/lua-format-integer)

How can I format an integer number lets say 1000000 in a way that it returns 1.000.000 ?

Is this managable by using `printf` ? Does someone know how to do it? what's the parameters like?

I'm currently using `Corona SDK` / `Lua` and there is a format function which is similar to `printf`.

Answer (score 3):

Format function with to C `printf` alike formatting in Lua is `string.format`.

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.format

Note that it does not support thousands separator, as it is not standard C89, but a SUSv2 extension.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a custom function. Something like:

```
function comma_value(amount)
  local formatted, k = amount, 0
  while true do  
    formatted, k = string.gsub(formatted, "^(-?%d+)(%d%d%d)", '%1,%2')
    if (not k) or k==0 then
      break
    end
  end
  return formatted
end
```

More [number formatting functions](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FormattingNumbers).

Comment: I'd add at least minimal validation — check that `amount` contains a number and / or that `formatted` and `k` are not `nil`. Infinite loops are nasty.

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh If the variable `amount` doesn't have a number, there wouldn't be any problem. `string.gsub` shall return the same string `formatted`.

Comment: Ah, missed that `-?`, clever.